# Translations on a general manifold

Tags: manifolds, taylor-expansion, vector-analysis, curvature

My question is simple (yet I can't find any clear answers): **How do we define infinitesimal translations of a vector on a general manifold ?**
Please, don't just answer with the correct definition, I would like to understand why it is the correct detention if need with some references (At a level that is understandable for a physics master)

What you can/can't use:

- There is a Levi-Cevita connexion $\nabla$ on the manifold
- if neccecairy you can use that the Riemann tensor vanishes
- There is no full set of killing vectors

**My attempt:**

I think that $A_\mu(x_\rho + \epsilon_\rho) = A_\mu(x_\rho) + \epsilon^\kappa\nabla_\kappa A_\mu(x_\rho)$ since this definition ensures that $A_\mu(x_\rho + \epsilon_\rho)$ is still a vector.

**Obvious other option**

Obviously the other option would be that $A_\mu(x_\rho + \epsilon_\rho) = A_\mu(x_\rho) + \epsilon^\kappa\partial_\kappa A_\mu(x_\rho)$ but this is no longer a vector (is it ?)

Comment: Moving a vector along a single path tells you nothing about the Riemann tensor. (Think of the equator of a sphere and the corresponding circle on a cylinder. Both are geodesics, both do exactly the same thing to the tangent space, one is on a manifold of constant curvature zero and the other on one of constant curvature related to the radius.)

Comment: I don't see why this is relevant ? You can always translate in a circle and than it does tell you something doesn't it ?